# Environmental variables are null during Azure Pipeline Build test

Tags: botframework, azure-pipelines

I've created a build pipeline for my chatbot that uses mocha tests as part of the process. All tests pass on my local with VS Code, but they are failing during the pipeline build. The issue is missing environmental variables. However, I have added for each run via variables and it is still not working *only in some cases*. Some of the variables are coming through fine, but other continue to be null (and are causing failure of the build). I have checked and all the variable names are identical to my local .env file. Any ideas why some of the variables are coming across as null during pipeline build where others are fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue between my local test environment being Windows command line and the build pipeline being ubuntu. On Windows environmental variables are not case sensitive, but they are on Linux platforms such as ubuntu. I changed by yml file to use `windows-latest` instead of `ubuntu-latest` for the build and that fixed the problem. The key takeaway is:

- Use Linux env variable naming regardless of your platform (all caps and underscores for spaces)

In case you already have many env variables in your project with mixed case, you can switch the OS in your build pipeline to Windows, but that is more of a workaround than a solution to the problem. That said, dealing with something relatively simple like botframework it should be fine to avoid having to recode and redefine all of your env variables.